# Windows 7 Environment Variable for System32 or SysWOW64

Tags: c#, environment-variables, flash, windows-7-x64, system32

Is there an environment variable to directly access `System32` or `SysWOW64` folder, respectively, in Windows 7 32bit or 64bit?

I know of a workaround by using `%WINDIR%\System32` which is not working for me.

I have to re-compile an EXE that refers to some OCX that should be registered in `System32` folder. The problem I am facing is that I have to install it in a 64bit system where the OCX got registered in `SysWOW64` folder and not getting registered in `System32` folder.

What should I try? Thanks for your help!

### Edit:

I figured out that the solution has a reference to a dll which refers to `flash10h.ocx`. For this `flash10h.ocx` has to be registered. I could get it registered in `SysWOW64` folder but not in `System32`. My system already has a flash player v11.xx. Will this not work?

Please help!

Comment: Wrong!!
On 64bit Windows: `system32 = 64bit libs` and `syswow64 = 32bit libs`
(contrary what folder names suggest)

Answer (score 5):

The following method will retrieve the path to the 32-bit system directory and, optionally, place it in the environment variable SYSDIR32.

```
public static String Get32BitSystemDirectory (Boolean placeInEnvironmentVariable = true)
{
   String sysDir = "";
   if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem) sysDir = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%\\SysWOW64");
   else sysDir = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%\\System32");
   if (placeInEnvironmentVariable) Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SYSDIR32", sysDir, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
   return sysDir;
}
```